# Images do not load on website in Safari (Mac 10.4)

Tags: html, image, macos, safari, osx-tiger

I'm having trouble with a website of ours that is not displaying images on Mac Safari

The exact same website is on a dedicated server and works fine.
When we moved it to a load balanced environment the images stop working only in Mac Safari, but still works in all other browsers including windows safari, and Firefox on the mac that had the original problem.

We tried other macs, and the problem only exists on macs running OS version 10.4.etc
The problem presents itself on ALL versions of safari on the Mac running 10.4, and the problem disappears on ALL versions of safari on Macs running other versions.

The website is built on Community Server.

I've done some googling, and I found various forums that mention the problem, however they are all from a client side perspective and they say that this issue only affects certain websites. I haven't found any developer related material that explains how to fix it from the code side.

I'm reaching out to the Mac website developers, because I am definitely not a Mac user, and I have no idea how to proceed. Any links or ideas that could get me started?

Comment: What kind of balancer are you using? What happens if you bypass the balancer (i.e. point Safari directly to a back-end server)?

Comment: When we bypass the balancer, and hit the site directly on each server, the issue persists.

Comment: Bring up the Safari Activity window (Menu Window->Activity) and look for 404s for the missing images. Do they look as expected? Are you dynamically creating the image URLs (e.g. javascript) in a way that fails on 10.4?

Comment: can you post a snip of the HTML output? sometimes some browsers auto-handle glitchy file paths and maybe this browser is being more strict? e.g. IE will let you put the wrong slashes in your file path `\\` vs. the correct `/`.

Answer (score 0):

You can solve this by

1. making sure Safari's proxy is set properly
2. bypassing Safari's cache when refreshing

Comment: Is this client-side or server-side? How do I do it? and if it's a client-side fix, how do I modified the code to not present this issue?

Comment: I'm just talking about Safari settings; I couldn't tell you where in Safari's menu structure to find them exactly, but I'm sure it's not too hard!